# How to select recent updates to a table in sybase

Tags: sql, sap-ase

In Sybase database how do you select from a table the most current rows since the last select? I think need to keep a counter or something. How do you normally do it? thanks

Answer (score 2):

- Create another column in your table say `last_update_time` or
  `create_time` if you are not updating any records in it. Populate it
  with current timestamp for any insert or update.
- Create another table, lets say `audit` with only rows, which would
  store `last_read_time`.
- Now when you pull data from main table, select then
  `max(last_update_time)` and store it in `audit.last_read_time`.
- From next run, select date where `last_update_time` `>`
  `audit.last_read_time`

Comment: Ok thanks. I guess another way not to tax my database too much is to create this tracking mechanism on my file system.